# I use Flask-Admin ModelView. I want to know which field in the model is changed when calling `after_model_change`

Tags: flask, flask-admin

```
class View(ModelView):    
    def after_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if model.is_enabled:
            subject = "subject"
            template = render_template('template.html')

            mail.send_email(from_email='example@mail.com',
                          to_email=model.email, subject=subject, text=template)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution. edit_form method instantiate model editing form, and I take the value I need. After that in after_model_change method, I check if this value is changed and decide whether to send the email.

```
class View(ModelView):    
    def after_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if self.user_is_enabled != model.is_enabled:
            if model.is_enabled:
                subject = "subject"
                template = render_template('template.html')

                mail.send_email(from_email='example@mail.com',
                              to_email=model.email, subject=subject, text=template)

    def edit_form(self, obj=None):
        try:
            self.user_is_enabled = obj.is_enabled
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        return ModelView.edit_form(self, obj)
```